# Play framework: Host repo.typesafe.com not found

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

Environment: Play framework; activator-1.3.2; Play-Java Web Application

build.sbt -

```
name := """ProjectDemoNew"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers +="Local Maven Repository" at "file:///home/shiva/.m2/repository"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "3.2.3.RELEASE",
   "org.springframework" % "spring-aop" % "3.2.3.RELEASE",
   "org.springframework" % "spring-expression" % "3.2.3.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-test" % "3.2.3.RELEASE",
  "com.mycomp.config"%"platform-config"%"0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

$ activator run

gives the following error(s) when the internet is down..

```
--
--
        [info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
        [warn] Host repo.typesafe.com not found. url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/mycomp/conf/i/platform-config/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/...-SNAPSHOT.pom
    --
    --
```

I am not seeing any errors in case the internet is up. 
There are lots of posts, but the answers seem to vary a lot.

All jars ( spring, application-specific, third party..) are in my local repository. But it always connects internet for refreshing dependencies, build is slow when the internet speed is not good

How to make Play go through Local repository without going through internet/offline? This helps me doing the build quickly with no or weak internet connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It automatically checks the internet for *SNAPSHOT* dependencies.
If you don't want it to do it, add :

```
offline := true
```

to your `build.sbt` file.

Comment: Let me try that change.

Comment: It seems to be working. When the internet is down, it is doing updates from local repository.